# unwanted space in custom font in php script

Tags: php

Hello i created kind of a custom font. Now I want to use it in my php script, everything is fine till i want use `s` letter with acute, because instead of just a letter i get letter+space. Here is my `font.php` :

```
<?php
$type='TrueType';
$name='TimesNewRomanPSMT';
$desc=array('Ascent'=>891,'Descent'=>-216,'CapHeight'=>7,'Flags'=>32,'FontBBox'=>'[-77 -226 936 886]','ItalicAngle'=>0,'StemV'=>70,'MissingWidth'=>778);
$up=-109;
$ut=49;
$cw=array(
0=>778,1=>778,2=>778,3=>778,4=>778,5=>778,6=>778,7=>778,8=>778,9=>778,
10=>778,11=>778,12=>778,13=>778,14=>778,15=>778,16=>778,17=>778,18=>778,19=>778,
20=>778,21=>778,22=>778,23=>778,24=>778,25=>778,26=>778,27=>778,28=>778,29=>778,
30=>778,31=>778,32=>250,33=>333,34=>408,35=>500,36=>500,37=>833,38=>778,39=>180,
40=>333,41=>333,42=>500,43=>564,44=>250,45=>333,46=>250,47=>278,48=>500,49=>500,
50=>500,51=>500,52=>500,53=>500,54=>500,55=>500,56=>500,57=>500,58=>278,59=>278,
60=>564,61=>564,62=>564,63=>444,64=>921,65=>722,66=>667,67=>667,68=>722,69=>611,
70=>556,71=>722,72=>722,73=>333,74=>389,75=>722,76=>611,77=>889,78=>722,79=>722,
80=>556,81=>722,82=>667,83=>556,84=>611,85=>722,86=>722,87=>944,88=>722,89=>722,
90=>611,91=>333,92=>278,93=>333,94=>469,95=>500,96=>333,97=>444,98=>500,99=>444,
100=>500,101=>444,102=>333,103=>500,104=>500,105=>278,106=>278,107=>500,108=>278,109=>778,
110=>500,111=>500,112=>500,113=>500,114=>333,115=>389,116=>278,117=>500,118=>500,119=>722,
120=>500,121=>500,122=>444,123=>480,124=>200,125=>480,126=>541,127=>778,128=>778,129=>778,
130=>778,131=>778,132=>778,133=>778,134=>778,135=>778,136=>778,137=>778,138=>778,139=>778,
140=>778,141=>778,142=>778,143=>778,144=>778,145=>778,146=>778,147=>778,148=>778,149=>778,
150=>778,151=>778,152=>778,153=>778,154=>778,155=>778,156=>778,157=>778,158=>778,159=>778,
160=>250,161=>722,162=>333,163=>611,164=>500,165=>611,166=>556,167=>500,168=>333,169=>556,
170=>556,171=>611,172=>611,173=>333,174=>611,175=>611,176=>400,177=>444,178=>333,179=>278,
180=>333,181=>406,182=>389,183=>333,184=>333,185=>389,186=>389,187=>427,188=>444,189=>333,
190=>444,191=>444,192=>667,193=>722,194=>722,195=>722,196=>722,197=>611,198=>667,199=>667,
200=>667,201=>611,202=>611,203=>611,204=>611,205=>333,206=>333,207=>722,208=>722,209=>722,
210=>722,211=>722,212=>722,213=>722,214=>722,215=>564,216=>667,217=>722,218=>722,219=>722,
220=>722,221=>722,222=>611,223=>500,224=>333,225=>444,226=>444,227=>444,228=>444,229=>278,
230=>444,231=>444,232=>444,233=>444,234=>444,235=>444,236=>444,237=>278,238=>278,239=>646,
240=>500,241=>500,242=>500,243=>500,244=>500,245=>500,246=>500,247=>549,248=>333,249=>500,
250=>500,251=>500,252=>500,253=>500,254=>278,255=>333);

$enc='iso-8859-2';
$diff='131 /.notdef 136 /.notdef 140 /Sacute /Tcaron 143 /Zacute 152 /.notdef 156 /sacute /tcaron 159 /zacute 161 /caron /breve /Lslash 165 /Aogonek 170 /Scedilla 175 /Zdot 178 /ogonek /lslash 185 /aogonek /scedilla 188 /Lcaron /hungarumlaut /lcaron /zdot /Racute 195 /Abreve 197 /Lacute /Cacute 200 /Ccaron 202 /Eogonek 204 /Ecaron 207 /Dcaron /Dslash /Nacute /Ncaron 213 /Odblacute 216 /Rcaron /Uring 219 /Udblacute 222 /Tcedilla 224 /racute 227 /abreve 229 /lacute /cacute 232 /ccaron 234 /eogonek 236 /ecaron 239 /dcaron /dmacron /nacute /ncaron 245 /odblacute 248 /rcaron /uring 251 /udblacute 254 /tcedilla /dotaccent';
$file='times.z';
$originalsize=409280;
// --- EOF ---
```

What should i do to get `Ś` instead of `Ś with space`?

Comment: What renders this "custom font"`, and how do you output it?

Comment: So I used one of tutorials and I converted `TTF` font like:
`ttf2afm times.ttf > times.afm
php fonts/utils/makefont.php times.ttf times.afm cp1250
cp times.* fonts/` and i use it for generating PDF files using TCPDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the Array `$cw` contains the character width of each character:

- Character `0x53 (83)` (S in `ASCII`) has a width of `556`
- Character `0x73 (115)` (s in `ASCII`) has a width of `389`
- Character `0x8C (140)` (Ś in `cp1250`) has a width of `778`
- Character `0x9C (156)` (ś in `cp1250`) has a width of `778`
- Character `0xA6 (166)` (Ś in `iso-8859-2`) has a width of `556`
- Character `0xB6 (182)` (ś in `iso-8859-2`) has a width of `389`

Now I do not know where those widths are really from, but it may be because you -- output? -- the font using the `cp1250` code page (you wrote this in the comment), but set the encoding in your source code to `iso-8859-2`. You can look up the differences between the two code pages at [Wikipedia Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)

So you can either export that again with the `iso-8859-2` code page, change the code page in your script, or alter the widths manually. Keep in mind that there are other characters that differ in those two code pages, so you probably want to change them too.

Comment: changing this manually has no effect I mean i did change character 193=>554 and i see no change

Comment: This is because it seems I am blind, as &Sacute; is `A6` (166) and not `C1` (193), no Idea how I got the idea... (You should revert that change) It could still happen due to the code page though, see if changing 156 (cp1250 lowercase &sacute;) or 140 (cp1250 uppercase &Sacute;) improves your rendering

Comment: Its probably stupid question but assuming I cannot change those values manually ( cause I did with no result just now) how can export it? You mean like use `makefont.php` script again?

Comment: Since you did not share the script, the "tutorial", nor how you further use those font settings in TCPDF, I really have no way to know so I can only speculate anyway, but yes that would be my guess.